# Solutions for compiling C# to SWF/Actionscript

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript-3

Are there any good solutions out there for compiling C# code to an SWF or to actionscript?

Comment: Whoa, icons in tags!  What'll they think of next?

Comment: Do those icons qualify as spam? I've never marked anything as spam before, so I've got an itchy trigger-finger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joa ebert is investigating the subject:
http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2009/09/28/compiling-java-and-c-to-swf/

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you cannot find a good work-around you may consider using silverlight rather than Flash.

Comment: This is one of the things we're looking at, however flash is more likely to be already installed on a given system, and that's what we're looking for.

Comment: In that case it is a matter of knowing your customers. Are they naive and are unwilling to upgrade or download anything or do you think they are more computer-hip? If the latter; just look how http://www.silverlight.net encourages users to install Silverlight 3.0. It brings up a sign saying you should install Silverlight 3.0 or upgrade. If a user declines then it shows your a water-downed version of the site. If user accepts then you get the full site. I doubt if you will find a good framework for combining .NET with Actionscript; so you have to pick the lesser evil (.NET or SWF).

Comment: naivete doesn't have anything to do with not upgrading.  We have trouble with our customers not wanting to upgrade software all the time, and it's generally due to their IT departments.  Individuals who don't know what they're doing are generally fine upgrading, but many in large organizations are not allowed to (for various different reasons).

Answer (score 0):

no...however there is a [c/c++ to flash bytecode compiler](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at WebOrb from midnightCoders. After adding your lib to the bin directory you can then use the management console to browse to your library then select code generation that will generate limited actionScript code from a dll.

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html

This will only produce the actionScript you still would need to call the remote object to call the functions it will not compile the internals of the C# code into actionScript.